# grails 3 mongodb: Method on class [] was used outside of a Grails application

Tags: mongodb, controller, grails-3.0

I am using the following:

- Grails Version: 3.0.1
- Groovy Version: 2.4.3
- JVM Version: 1.8.0_05
- mongodb: 3.0.3

I have two domain objects that look like this:

```
class PhoneNumber {
    String country
    String numberString

    static constraints = {
        country nullable: false, size: 2..2
        numberString nullable: false, blank: false, size: 1..16
    }
}
```

and

```
class Contact {
    String name

    static hasMany = [phoneNumber: PhoneNumber]

    static embedded = ['phoneNumber']
    static constraints = { }
}
```

I have a controller that looks like this:

```
class ContactController extends RestfulController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    ContactController() { super(Contact) }


    @Transactional
    def save(Contact contact) {
        println contact
        response.status = 201
        def result = [:]
        result.id = 1
        render result as JSON
    }
}
```

When I POST to the controller via:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:8080/contact" -d "@contact.json"
```

I get a response of `{"id":1}`. However if I add the following line to my Contact and PhoneNumber domain objects:

```
static mapWith = 'mongo'
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - IllegalStateException occurred when processing request: [POST] /contact - parameters:
{"id":null,"name":"Full Name","phoneNumber":[{"country":"ca","numberString":"18095551212"},{"country":"ca","numberString":"16135551212"}]}: 
Method on class [xxx.Contact] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.. Stacktrace follows:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [demo.Contact] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
at  grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93) ~[grails-core-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:90) ~[grails-core-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
```

What else needs to be done to get mongodb domain objects marshalled on a POST?

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly define the `id` field as an `ObjectId` when using MongoDB.

**domain/com/example/Book.groovy**

```
package com.example

import org.bson.types.ObjectId

class Book {

   ObjectId id
   String   title
   String   author

   static mapWith = "mongo"

}
```

BSON IDs are not simple `long` numbers — they contain four parts, including a timestamp.  When converted to a `String` (example: `book.id as String`), the ID will be 24 characters long and look something like: **`"556a7299aa2437211f8e4e73"`**

See:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId